# Show a loop result in a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, logging

I'm a newbie and I'm having trouble to do something that might be really simple. I have a Javascript code that gets a random number of elements from an array. I need to show this elements ia a HTML, I'm building this functionality at jsfiddle. How can I show the array elements in HTML, instead of alert box or console log and make the code run by pressing the html button?

Here is my JS:
https://jsfiddle.net/TasGuerciMaia/5Luy83uf/1/

```
function get(music, count) {
var mix = music.slice(0), i = music.length, min = i - count, temp, index;
while (i-- > min) {
    index = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());
    temp = mix[index];
    mix[index] = mix[i];
    mix[i] = temp;
}
return mix.slice(min);
}


var numbers = ['1','2','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];
console.log ( get(numbers, 6) );
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="item"> </div>
<div> 
<script>  
</script>
</div>
<button class="validation">
Choose
</button>
```

Comment: SO do you know how to create an element or set html?

Comment: Do you know what HTML you want, to represent the results?

Comment: I don't. Is that? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: @loa_in_ What do you mean? I wan't to show the result on the <div> at the code. Is that what you asked?

Comment: Yeah. So as text then. Then @durbnpoisn's answer will do the trick. I tested it here: https://jsfiddle.net/4z7q0zdq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call your function and put the result into an "innerHTML" in the div you've already created.  You do this by setting the innerHTML to the result (return) of the function.

```
function get(music, count) {
var mix = music.slice(0), i = music.length, min = i - count, temp, index;
while (i-- > min) {
    index = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());
    temp = mix[index];
    mix[index] = mix[i];
    mix[i] = temp;
}
return mix.slice(min);
}
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = get(music, count);
```

In your HTML, simply id the div as "results"

```
<div class="item"> </div>
<div id="results"> 

</div>
<button class="validation">
Choose
</button>
```

Comment: Great @durnmpoisn Thank you :)